# See Facebook posts made on my behalf by apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Is it possible to view all Facebook posts that have been made on my behalf by Facebook apps that I have authorized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe there is a way to filter your posts to view only ones made by an app. You will have to manually go through all your posts.

If you are worried about apps making posts on your behalf you can check your activity log:

> `https://www.facebook.com/Your_Username/allactivity`

Comment: This doesnt show everything. The Pinterest app obviously makes posts on my behalf, as people sometimes like my Pinterest activity. Yet my pinterest activity is not listed on my activity page. This advice must not apply to all apps.